# Number guessing game not outputting right

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a number guessing game where the user enters number integers they want to guess and the range of those integers 1 to (m). Then the computer randomly generates numbers in that range for the user to guess. The user guesses until they get all the numbers correct For example:

```
Enter number integers: 4
Enter the range of those integers from 1 to (m): 6
Enter guess: 2 3 1 4 
3 of your guesses are correct. Guess Again
Enter guess: 2 3 1 6
Correct. Would you like to play again.
```

The Output I get right now is:

Enter number integers: 4

Enter the range of those integers from 1 to (m): 6

Enter your guesses for the 4 in the range from 1 to 6 that you have selected: 2 3 1 4

Then after you enter the guesses nothing else happens with the program. I'm confused on why the game is not saying how many guesses where correct.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong to get this output. I'm also getting no warnings or errors from my code.

There are three files for this `game.cpp`, `game.h`, and `driver.cpp`. Please let me know if you find anything else wrong with my code. This is my 1st program I have wrote in C++.

---

```
    //game.cpp
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "Game.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // generateNumbers: Fucntion to generate numbers between 1 to (m) and 
    // generate as many has user wanted.
    // n: the amount of integers
    // m: the max number the user wants
    // numbers: returns the numbers generated by the computer
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int*Game:: generateNumbers(int n, int m) {
    
        // Intialize random number
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    
        // Declare array size to generate random numbers based on what is between 1 to (m)
        int* numbers = new int[n];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (rand() % m) +1;
            cin >> numbers[i];
    
        }
    
        return numbers;
    
    
    }
    
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // guessingGame: See's how many numbers the user got to correct until they win the game.
    // n: the amount of integers
    // m: the max number the user wants
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Game::guessingGame(int n, int m) {
        int* p;
        int sum = 0;
    
        // Call the generateNumber function
        generateNumbers(n, m);
        
        // Declare array based on user guesses
        inputGuess = new int[n];
    
        p = generateNumbers(n,m);
    
        // Loop for User guesses for the integers
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> inputGuess[i];
        }

        // See if the user guesses and computers answers match up
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (p[i] == inputGuess[j]){
                    sum++;
                    break;
            }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//driver.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Game.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        //Declare variables
        Game guess;
        int n;
        int m;
        int userNumbers = guess.getNumbers();
    
        // Prompt the user to enter integers and range
        
            // Have user enter number of integers they want
            cout << "Enter the Number of the Integers (n):  ";
            cin >> n;
    
            // Have user enter the range if integers between 1 to m
            cout << "Enter the Number of Each Integers from 1 to (m):  ";
            cin >> m;
    
            // guesses from user are not correct then user needs to keep guessing 
            while (userNumbers != n) {
                cout << "Enter your guesses for the " << n << " " << "in the range from 1 to " << m << " " << "that you have been selected: "; 
                cin >> userNumbers;
                guess.guessingGame(n, m);
            }
    
        // If the user has guessed the correct numbers and would like to play again
        if (sizeof(userNumbers) == n) {
            cout << "You are correct! Play Again?";
        }
        // If numbers guessed not correct then display how many are correct
        else {
            cout << sizeof(userNumbers) << "of your guesses are correct." << endl;
        }
    
    };
        
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//game.h file
    class Game{
    public:
        // Get what numbers the users have guessed are correct
        int getNumbers() {
            return number;
        }
    
    
        // Generate random numbers between the range set by user
        int* generateNumbers(int n, int m);
    
        // Begin the guessing game
        void guessingGame(int n, int m);
    
    private:
        int number; // numbers that are correct
        int* randomNumbers; // random numbers generated
        int* inputGuess; // users guesses 
    
    };
```

Comment: I don't think `sizeof` is giving you what you think it is...

Comment: If you used `std::vector`, instead of arrays, you could use `std::vector::size()` to get the size of the vector.

Comment: You don't do anything with `sum` after you calculated it. It was supposed to be the number of correct guesses but you threw the calculation away instead of using it.

Comment: `sizeof(userNumbers)` is a compile time constant telling you the # of bytes in a single integer on your platform. This has nothing to do with a solution.

Comment: `int userNumbers;` is a single `int` not an array. my tips: 1) use `std::vector` and stay away from `int* numbers = new int[n];`, it comes with more pitfalls than you might imagine 2) write less code and more tests, you have lots of code with lots of problems, if you first test, only then write more it will be simpler 3) use `std::vector` 4) `std::vector`

Comment: `int userNumbers = guess.getNumbers();` happens before the game begins. And you also reuse `userNumbers` later.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of issues in your code.

- `srand` should not be called each time you want to roll random numbers, but only once (eg in `main`)
- `rand` is of poor quality. In addition to that, distributions obtained via `%` are usually not uniform (suppose largest random number is `...108` then `%10==9` will have one count less than `%10 == i`). Take a look at [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) if you need better randomness.
- `inputGuess = new int[n];` for dynamic arrays is problematic. When a class manages a resource (eg a dynamically allocated array) it must follow the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) or it must be considered broken (in particular, copying your `Game` will cause problems). Prefer the rule of 0 (same link) when possible and use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.
- also because of `inputGuess = new int[n];`, your code has lots of memory leaks. If you really do use `new` you must `delete` anything that was created via `new`. Here a vector is the right choice, other uses of `new` are covered by smart pointers.
- The logic of the code is difficult to decipher, mainly because you seem to confuse `int` with arrays and 2d arrays of `int`s.

I could probably continue the list, but anyhow I suggest you to start from scratch. You wrote to much code at once and now are faced with lots of issues. Try to test more. Make a plan of what you want to implement, write a test (that can only fail for now), then write the code that makes the test pass. In this way you always have to deal with at most one or two problems, not all at once.

To give you only a rough sketch of how your code could look like with `std::vector`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Game {
    Game(size_t num,int min,int max){
        for (size_t i=0;i<num;++i) hiddenNumbers.push_back( rand()%(max-min) + min);
    }
    void reveal(){
        for (const auto& n : hiddenNumbers) std::cout << n << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    bool guess(int x){
        --num_guesses;
        auto it = std::find(hiddenNumbers.begin(),hiddenNumbers.end(),x);
        if (it == hiddenNumbers.end()) return false;
        hiddenNumbers.erase(it);
        return true;
    }
    bool has_more_guesses(){ return num_guesses > 0; }
    int remaining() { return num_guesses; }
    private:
        int num_guesses = 5;
        std::vector<int> hiddenNumbers;

};

int main(){
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    Game g{10,2,5};
    while (g.has_more_guesses()) {
        bool correct = g.guess(2);
        if (correct) std::cout << "Yay. Guessed numbeer was corerct! \n";
        std::cout << "you have " << g.remaining() << " remaining guesses\n";
        std::cout << "spoiler altert! Secret numbers are: ";
        g.reveal();
    } 
}
```

Each game has maximum 5 trials. If you still continue to call `guess` the counter `num_guesses` will get negative. You might want to fix that. When a number is found `guess` returns `true` and the number is erased from the private vector.

[Possible output:](https://godbolt.org/z/vzc55r6vf)

```
Yay. Guessed numbeer was corerct! 
you have 4 remaining guesses
spoiler altert! Secret numbers are: 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 2 3 
Yay. Guessed numbeer was corerct! 
you have 3 remaining guesses
spoiler altert! Secret numbers are: 3 4 2 3 4 4 2 3 
Yay. Guessed numbeer was corerct! 
you have 2 remaining guesses
spoiler altert! Secret numbers are: 3 4 3 4 4 2 3 
Yay. Guessed numbeer was corerct! 
you have 1 remaining guesses
spoiler altert! Secret numbers are: 3 4 3 4 4 3 
you have 0 remaining guesses
spoiler altert! Secret numbers are: 3 4 3 4 4 3
```